# Floating last <li> to the right inside <nav>

Tags: html, css

I can't get how to float the last `<li>` to the right of a `<nav>`,

my html code is:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">LastItem</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

When I use `<li style="float:right"><a href="">LastItem</a></li>`
is displaying good.

but when using an id:

```
<li id="last"><a href="">LastItem</a></li>
```

and

```css
#last {
  float: right;
}
```

it's not displayed correctly.

How can I get this working?

Comment: there's no difference for the final result: could you post a fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: that works... http://jsfiddle.net/L4SFZ/1/ your issue is either the style is being overridden somewhere else or maybe javascript might be involved... hard to tell

Comment: you have not added Id `right` to the last li

Comment: in your website you have no style associated to #right

Comment: thank you is good now, i missed to upload the new style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the stylesheet of [your website](http://www.autoshkollaonline.com/new/) you have no style associated to the `#right` list-item, so it will be left-floated because of this rule

```
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

So, just add

```
#right {
    float: right 
}
```

or you can also use `:last-child` pseudoelement (on modern browser, not on `IE<9`) and save an `id` attribute on the markup

```
nav ul li:last-child {
    float: right 
}
```

Comment: I applied the :last-child and is working fine, thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no error in your code. There could be some CSS that is conflicting with your code. Check your css properly.

Answer (score -1):

its working fine

css

```
#last{
    float: right;
   }
```

html code.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
    <li id="last"><a href="">LastItem</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

try this

Comment: there is no element `<last>`, only `<li id="last">`. Your css does not work.